# Concatenate Multiple lines into a single line until a pattern is found

Tags: text-processing

With AWK and SED patterns i ended up with a file similar to

```
|
9000
3000
1000
0000
0000
2000
1000
2000
|
5669000
518000
3000
16000
0000
28000
2241000
2841000
|
9020000
453000
520000
4000
2852000
5191000
75000
|
```

Is it possible to concatenate the lines seperated between the "|" into a single line separated by commas?

```
9000,3000,1000,0000,0000,2000,1000,2000
5669000,518000,3000,16000,0000,28000,2241000,2841000
9020000,453000,520000,4000,2852000,5191000,75000
```

i used paste to do this but it produces undesired results since the number of lines between the "|" is not equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` solution.  Suspect it's a bit long-winded.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="|"}NF>1{print substr(gensub(/\n/,",","g"),2,length($0)-2)}' file
9000,3000,1000,0000,0000,2000,1000,2000
5669000,518000,3000,16000,0000,28000,2241000,2841000
9020000,453000,520000,4000,2852000,5191000,75000
$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWqUap1s/NzrC6oCgzr0ShuDSpuKRIIz01D8jS0I/J09dRAsF0JU0dI52c1Lz0kgwNFQNNXSPN2v//a7gsDQwMuIxBhCGIMIATRnAxMKuGy9TMDKzY1NACoccMoR4samRkAtFjAaFBFhiB5U1MwTpMoTyIIjAPaKIlWLG5KVgLAA)

Comment: It's not really any less long-winded, but you could do it all via separators i.e. `awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n?\\|\n"; FS="\n"; OFS=","} {$1=$1} NR>1'`

Comment: Thanks for all the awesome answers. it was much more interesting to pass this entire solution into an echo statement(i was generating this awk statement to run as a part of another script!)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work nicely:

```
$ tr "|\n" "\n," < input | sed 's/^,//;s/,$//'
9000,3000,1000,0000,0000,2000,1000,2000
5669000,518000,3000,16000,0000,28000,2241000,2841000
9020000,453000,520000,4000,2852000,5191000,75000
```

We use `tr` to translate `|`s into new lines, and newlines into `,`s.  We then take the resultant output and strip and leading or trailing `,`s with `sed`.

Comment: Good elegant solution.  But I feel compelled to mention you've an unnecessary cat there.

Comment: I have saved the poor `cat` from useless toil.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ':L; ${s/\n/,/g; s/,|,/\n/g; s/|,\|,|//g};  N; bL;' file
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it could be :

```
perl -nF'\|\n' -a0777e 'print s/\n(?!\z)/,/gr for @F' input.file
```

**Explanation:**

- Slurp the file `-0777` and then have it split on `-F\|\n` ,i.e., wherever we see a pipe character followed by a newline character.
- The `-a` option will store the split fields into the array `@F`, which is zero-indexed.
- The first element of the array `@F`, viz., `$F[0]` would be empty so wouldn't show up when it is printed.
- The `for` loop loops over all the elements of the array `@F` and for each element, it changes all those newlines that do not see an end-of-string to their immediate right, `(?!\z)`, are substituted for a comma.

**Output:**

```
9000,3000,1000,0000,0000,2000,1000,2000
5669000,518000,3000,16000,0000,28000,2241000,2841000
9020000,453000,520000,4000,2852000,5191000,75000
```

Another method using `POSIX`*ly* `sed` editor. Here we load the pattern space as much as is needed to arrive at the decision to print it:

```
sed -e '
    /|$/!ba
    1d;s/\n|$//
    :b;y/\n/,/;b
    :a;$bb
    N;H;s/.*//;x;D
' input.file
```

In this method we slurp  the file:

```
sed -e '
    $!{                 ;# provided we"re not at the eof
        N;H;s/.*//;x;D  ;# we stick the next line to the PS & keep doing it till we hit the eof.
    }

    ;# here we have the whole file loaded into the pattern space, PS
    s/^|\n//;s/\n|$//   ;# take away the leading and trailing pipes
    s/\n|\n/,/g         ;# the internal pipes are changed to commas
    y/\n,/,\n/          ;# interchange the newlines <=> commas
' input.file
```

With `GNU sed` it can be done by setting up a do-until loop to load up the pattern space while we have not yet seen the |. Note: with this we are assuming the last and first lines of the input are necessarily a |.

```
sed -e '
    1d
    :loop
        $!N
        s/\n|//
    Tloop
    y/\n/,/
' input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vRS='|' -vOFS=, '$1=$1""' infile
```

- The `RS='|'`, changes the awk's default **R**ecord **S**eperator which it `\n`ewline to a pipe `|` instead.
- The `OFS=,`, changes the awk's default **O**utput **F**ield **S**eperator which is a space to a comma `,` instead.
- The `$1==$1` (you can use any filed) causes the re-evaluation of `$0` (known whole line in awk) and will join the fields based on RS as `|` and OFS as `,`.
- Double quotes  in `'$1=$1""'` is used to force awk to string assignment, so a line with only zero(s) will not be deleted.
- **Output is:**

  ```
  9000,3000,1000,0000,0000,2000,1000,2000
  5669000,518000,3000,16000,0000,28000,2241000,2841000
  9020000,453000,520000,4000,2852000,5191000,75000
  ```