# Concatenate Multiple lines into a single line until a pattern is found without loosing the first part of pattern

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following pattern:

```
i-095erwr244r22cfeaa
TF-CLIENT
TF-StKML2
i-0c23232ac153534c5d
TF-CLIENT
TF-COMMON
TF-STEERR
i-043434e0934347eb5
TF-CLIENT
TF-ADFS
TF-COMMON
TF-STCLUSTER_1
TF-SwewCLUSTER3
```

I want the following output

```
i-095erwr244r22cfeaa,TF-COMMON;TF-StKML2;
i-0c23232ac153534c5d,TF-CLIENT;TF-COMMON;TF-STEERR;
i-043434e0934347eb5,TF-CLIENT;TF-ADFS;TF-COMMON;TF-STCLUSTER_1;TF-SwewCLUSTER3
```

I tried like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="i-"}NF>1{print substr(gensub(/\n/,";","g"),0,length($0)-0)}' sg1.txt
```

Base on similar post [in here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463269/397837) and I get the following

```
095erwr244r22cfeaa;TF-COMMON;TF-StKML2;
0c23232ac153534c5d;TF-CLIENT;TF-COMMON;TF-STEERR;
043434e0934347eb5;TF-CLIENT;TF-ADFS;TF-COMMON;TF-STCLUSTER_1;TF-SwewCLUSTER3
```

So it is cutting the beginning of the pattern 'i-0' and it add semicolon to all output, I need the first one to be a comma. I thought about using **sed** to replace the first semicolon in the results, but how can I get the full output at the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk '/^i-/{if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$0 ","; next} {rec=rec $0 ";"} END{print rec}' file
i-095erwr244r22cfeaa,TF-CLIENT;TF-StKML2;
i-0c23232ac153534c5d,TF-CLIENT;TF-COMMON;TF-STEERR;
i-043434e0934347eb5,TF-CLIENT;TF-ADFS;TF-COMMON;TF-STCLUSTER_1;TF-SwewCLUSTER3;
```

or, depending if you want a semi-colon at the end of every line or not:

```
$ awk '/^i-/{if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$0; sep=","; next} {rec=rec sep $0; sep=";"} END{print rec}' file
i-095erwr244r22cfeaa,TF-CLIENT;TF-StKML2
i-0c23232ac153534c5d,TF-CLIENT;TF-COMMON;TF-STEERR
i-043434e0934347eb5,TF-CLIENT;TF-ADFS;TF-COMMON;TF-STCLUSTER_1;TF-SwewCLUSTER3
```

Comment: Be aware that you are separating all by commas, when it's the first comma and then semi-colon.

Comment: @guillermochamorro well spotted, fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

My GNU `sed`, `tr` proposal:

```
tr '\n' ';' < file | sed -E 's/(i-0[^;]*);/\n\1,/g'
```

Output:

```
i-095erwr244r22cfeaa,TF-CLIENT;TF-StKML2;
i-0c23232ac153534c5d,TF-CLIENT;TF-COMMON;TF-STEERR;
i-043434e0934347eb5,TF-CLIENT;TF-ADFS;TF-COMMON;TF-STCLUSTER_1;TF-SwewCLUSTER3;
```

Comment: Although there's a ";" in the end of the last record, don't know if that's wrong for OP.

Comment: Nice and simple, but you are introducing a spurious EOL at output''s beginning and missing one at output's end.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
BEGIN { RS="i-" }
NF>1 {
    print substr( gensub(/\n/,";","g"), 0, length($0)-0)
}
```

Here, you are converting multiple lines into a single record, separated by "i-", so that is lost right away, and converting  NL ("\n") to ';'s.
The substr does not seem to do much for you.

[gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) itself applied repetetively does what you need, as here...

```
BEGIN { RS="i-" }
NF>1 {
    print gensub("^(.*);$", "i-\\1", "g", gensub(/\n/,";","g"))
}
```

This relies on the inner gensub doing what you were doing earlier, concatenating multiple fields, converting NL to ';'.  The outer simly takes that as input, adds the "i-" back to the beginning and trims the ';' at the end.

In 1-line then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="i-"}NF>1{print gensub("^(.*);$", "i-\\1", "g", gensub(/\n/,";","g"))}' sg1.txt
```

This is a rather complex way of doing things.  Somewhat more natural is to simply express what you are doing, like so:

```
/^i-/ {
    if (line) print line;
    line=$0;
    next
}
{
    line = line";"$0
}
END {
    if (line) print line
}
```

When you see a line with ^i-, print old state and start a new line.  The rest, append.  rinse, repeat.
Remember to print at the end.

The first time, test and print.  At END, test and print, in case you got an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Printing every record (line) with a terminal `;` except when the line starts with a `i-` will print like this:

```
$ awk -vORS=\; '/^i-/{printf "%s%s,",a,$0 ; a="\n";next}1;END{printf "\n"}' file

i-095erwr244r22cfeaa,TF-CLIENT;TF-StKML2;
i-0c23232ac153534c5d,TF-CLIENT;TF-COMMON;TF-STEERR;
i-043434e0934347eb5,TF-CLIENT;TF-ADFS;TF-COMMON;TF-STCLUSTER_1;TF-SwewCLUSTER3;
```